# Adding directory (header and source) to autocompletition search

Tags: autocompletion, path

I use Ctrl+P and Ctrl-N for autocompletition, and since I have library sources in another directory, like

```
/opt/ST/STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
/opt/ST/STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src
```

I would like to add these paths for autocompletition.
I tried to do

```
set path+=/opt/ST/STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/inc
set path+=/opt/ST/STM32F4xx_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.8.0/Libraries/STM32F4xx_StdPeriph_Driver/src
```

Changes to `path` variables are reflected correctly, but Ctrl-P and Ctrl-N don't search in these path too.

What is wrong in my setup ?

Comment: Check `:echo &path` to make sure they are included, but also note that i dont think any of the autocompletion in vim uses path. You could try `<C-x><C-p>` or `<C-x><C-]>`

Answer (score 2):

```
set complete=.,w,b,u,t,i
```

the `i` flag makes vim autocompletion search the including files.

Also, you can use `gf` command at the including file to verify vim can actually find the file.

However, `i` flag may slows down vim autocompletion significantly depending on the including file size and I avoid to use it.